# Viewchild is undefined inside a specific method

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to disable a button until the input field has data.I am trying to achieve this with the below code.

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-input clear-input
      id="globalmsg-user-management-name"
      #nameInput>
    </ion-input>
</ion-row>

<ion-row>
    <ion-button
        #globalmsgAddButto
        id="globalmsg-user-management-add-button"
        (click)="addButtonClicked()"
        [disabled]="addButtonDisabled()"
        >
      <span>Add</span>
    </ion-button>
 </ion-row>
```

```
@ViewChild('nameInput') nameInput: ElementRef;
  addButtonDisabled()
  {    
    if ( this.nameInput.nativeElement.value === '') {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

But I get the following error "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined".
I could access this.nameInput in addButtonClicked() but not in addButtonDisabled().Can someone answer this Please?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do `[disabled]="addButtonDisabled()"`. That will call that function many times (and potentially before `nameInput` is initialized?) I'd do something like add a `isDisabled` property to the component, do `[disabled]="isDisabled"`, then have `addButtonClicked` update that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put static: true to ViewChild. By default it is false.

Defintion:

**static** - True to resolve query results before change detection runs, false to resolve after change detection. Defaults to false.

```
@ViewChild('nameInput', {static: true}) nameInput: ElementRef;
```

So nameInput should be available on ngOnInit.

For safety, you should also use safeCheck.

Optionally: better to change method name for better convention like isAddButtonDisabled.

```
  public isAddButtonDisabled(): boolean {    
    if (this.nameInput?.nativeElement?.value === '') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```